# Safe generation of Sequential Order Number resetting daily

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a requirement to generate Order Numbers in the format of yyyyMMddxxxxxx where xxxxxx is the number of Orders since midnight.

E.g 20120821000004 is the fourth order on the 21st of Aug 2012.  Up to 5 orders could be created per second so this is a performance consideration.

An obvious solution is to do something like the following to find the latest order to increment:

```
SELECT MAX (id) FROM table_name WHERE id LIKE '2012-08-21%'
```

But that is likely to run into performance problems.

The other option I have explored is creating a sequence which is used to drive the number component and use an insert trigger.  The problem with that approach is that you need some safe way of rolling over the sequence to zero at the start of the day, which could cause collisions/race conditions if the sequence isn't reset at exactly midnight.

Is there some trick I can use here with Oracle to make it airtight but also performant?

Comment: Is your intention to generate a gap-free sequence?  If so, that is going to force orders to be serialized-- if you're trying to process 5 orders per second, that is likely to be problematic.

Comment: Also, apart from the performance problem from serialization, it's impossible to have a gap-free sequence anyway, because of the possibility of rollbacks.

Comment: If I were in your shoes I'd go back and question the requirements. Why do they need the order numbers in this format? Why do they need them to be gapless? Do they need them to be ordered sequentially? In other words, I'd recommend just having a simple sequence to generate a simple unique Order ID, and have a separate column for the Order Date.

Comment: It's not strictly a requirement that the numbers are gapless.  I've got something working that is pretty similar in to pizen's approach without the gapless numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only going to do this in SQL without any external utilities I might keep two tables:

- Absolute order ID
- Date/order offset

The first table will be used to produce monotonically increasing, unique ID values. The second table will be used to track the daily offset from the first table to the daily ID. A row would be inserted upon the first order of the day and would be the date and the highest ID from the first table. The order ID can then be calculated by subtracting the ID offset in the second table from the new ID pulled from the first table.

You might consider tracking the orders in the DB internally using the integer absolute order ID and just using the date/offset data to produce the human-friendly information of date and daily order number on the fly or as a cross-reference.

Answer (score 1):

you could generate a new sequence for every new day.
give them a meaningful name like 'order_seq_20120821'.

- check if sequence for today exists
- if not create it  (handle concurrency here, another thread could have created it)
- then use it

not really a java question here, the client cannot handle database concurrency

Comment: so you want to use a unique sequence ? may be you can save the sequence last value of the previous day. using this you can re-calculate the id's order. but the comment is still valid : the client cannot handle database concurrency! it must be handled database side.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specifically an Oracle solution, but I'm thinking of having an order numbers table with three columns:  date, xxxxxx (as an int), and the order number.

Keep an index on (date, xxxxxxx).  Now, do the query as:

```
select max(id) from OrderNumbers where date = <date>
```

This will use the index and should speed operations.

Another idea is to keep a similar table, but only for the current date.  In this version, you would have a sequence/autoincrement column auto generate xxxxxx.  You can then use a trigger to calculate the order number and fetch back the last value inserted to create the new order number.  This might be the fastest method, especially when you consider the issue of locking the data.

Comment: Is `max(id)` going to be a race condition with simultaneous orders? Instead you could do an insert into the `OrderNumbers` table and then get the ID of the last insert (`SCOPE_IDENTITY` in SQL Server, not sure what it is in Oracle). That way you know you'll always have a unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a seqence starting with the next order id

```
CREATE SEQUENCE orders_seq
 START WITH     201208210000001
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 ;
```

and increment the sequence at midnight up to first next day id by a job:

```
 declare
  v_curr_id NUMBER;
  v_inc     NUMBER;
  v_next_val NUMBER;
 begin 
  select orders_seq.nextval into v_curr_id from dual;
  v_next_val := to_number(to_char(SYSDATE+1, 'yyyymmdd') || '000000');
  v_inc := v_next_val - v_curr_id;
  execute immediate ' alter sequence orders_seq increment by ' || v_inc ;
  select orders_seq.nextval into v_curr_id from dual;
  execute immediate ' alter sequence orders_seq increment by 1';
 end;
 /
```

Comment: What happens if the job fails to run?  It is possible that there will be collisions after the job does run and sets the sequence back to 0.

Comment: @anger: the idea is not to set the sequence back to 0, but increment it up to the next day id

Answer (score 0):

Create an Oracle sequence for each day of the week i.e.

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_MON
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 ORDER;

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TUE
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 ORDER;

ETC up to SEQ_SUN

Create an Oracle Stored Procedure that returns:
1. a datetime
2. a sequence number for the day of the week corresponding to above datetime

**Logic as per below:**
- Store current date and time in a variable
- Get day of week corresponding to date in variable.
*Note: Use a formula that is independent of NLS_TERRITORY setting. You could use: 1 + TRUNC (DT) - TRUNC (DT, 'IW') to get 1 for Mon.*
- Get next sequence from sequence corresponding to above day of the week
- Return the datetime in the variable and the new sequence number obtained above.

**Schedule Job:**
Create a scheduled job that runs at 1 a.m. (not midnight) every day to reset seq of previous day.

With the above approach, you are safe with 24X7 operations.

**IMPORTANT:**
The datetime returned should be used to timestamp your incoming request so that the timestamp of your request shall match the sequence number allotted to it. This is important for requests hitting just before midnight.